# Is there a way to check nested resources in react-admin's matchSuggestion?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-admin

The goal is to make an AutocompleteInput check for the filter value not only in the suggestion list directly, but also in the suggestions' references to different resources.
Specifically, say a Quote has a reference to a Contact and to an Address, and the user enters 'abc' in the input. Now, a Quote whose address contains 'abc' should also be displayed in the suggestion list.
The most elegant way would be to use the useGetOne hook like in the following code snippet but you can't call that hook from outside a React component.

```
const matchAnyNested = (filter, value) => {
  if (matchAnyField(filter, value)) return true;
  const { data: contact } = useGetOne('contacts', value.contact_id);
  if (matchAnyField(filter, contact)) return true;
  const { data: account } = useGetOne('accounts', contact.account_id);
  if (matchAnyField(filter, account)) return true;
  for (let item of value.part_items) {
    const part = useGetOne('parts', item.part_id);
    if (matchAnyField(filter, part)) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
[...]
<AutocompleteInput ... matchSuggestion={matchAnyNested} />
```

Is there a way to fetch records from within the matchSuggestion function or some other way to validate suggestions based on nested records ? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Because of the [React rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), this doesn't seem to be possible. I ended up implementing this filtering functionality in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The `useGetOne` hook, just like other dataProvider hooks, accepts an `enabled` option. The example from [the react-admin documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#synchronizing-dependant-queries) shows its usage:

```
// fetch posts
const { ids, data: posts, loading: isLoading } = useGetList(
    'posts',
    { page: 1, perPage: 20 },
    { field: 'name', order: 'ASC' },
    {}
);

// then fetch categories for these posts
const { data: categories, loading: isLoadingCategories } = useGetMany(
    'categories',
    ids.map(id=> posts[id].category_id),
    // run only if the first query returns non-empty result
    { enabled: ids.length > 0 }
);
```

It applies to your case:

```
const matchAnyNested = (filter, value) => {
  const { data: contact } = useGetOne(
    'contacts',
    value.contact_id,
    { enabled: !matchAnyField(filter, value) }
  );
  const { data: account } = useGetOne(
    'accounts',
    contact.account_id,
    { enabled: !matchAnyField(filter, contact) }
  );
  // ...
};
```

This won't solve your problem in the loop, though, because of the rules of hooks.

If you do need that loop, your best bet is to use [the useDataProvider hook](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usedataprovider-hook) to call the dataProvider directly:

```
const matchAnyNested = async (filter, value) => {
  const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
  if (matchAnyField(filter, value)) return true;
  const { data: contact } = await dataProvider.getOne('contacts', { id: value.contact_id });
  if (matchAnyField(filter, contact)) return true;
  const { data: account } = await dataProvider.getOne('accounts', { id: contact.account_id });
  if (matchAnyField(filter, account)) return true;
  for (let item of value.part_items) {
    const part = await dataProvider.getOne('parts', { id: item.part_id });
    if (matchAnyField(filter, part)) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about the `enabled` option. The hook in a loop problem can be avoided by calling getList() and then looping over the response's data.
The main problem I was asking for help with though is that matchSuggestion takes a function, so hooks can't be used at all to match suggestions. Is that simply a limit of React admin or is there another way to fetch records during the matching process ?
Thanks

Comment: You can dfine the function you pass to matchsuggestion in a React component, and in thaty component use a hook